# Pegar o dia inicial e o dia final da semana especificada

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Boa tarde, estou retornando do banco de dados o numero da semana no ano.

```
["data_hora"]=>
string(16) "19/11/2018 15:26"
["num_semana"]=>
string(2) "47"
```

Onde num_semana é o numero da semana do ano que a data 19/11/2018 esta inserida. Preciso de uma maneira pegar o primeiro dia da semana 47 (Domingo) e o ultimo dia (Sábado). Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso.

Comment: Algo parecido com `new DateTime('+46 weeks Sunday Jan 2018')`

Comment: Mais ou menos, porém eu preciso passar o valor de num_semana, e ele me dizer quando inicia e quanto termina. Exemplo num_semana = 1
`$inicio = 01/01/2018`
`$fim = 07/01/2018`

Comment: Exatamente. Só uma questão de substituir o valor.

Comment: `new DateTime('+46 weeks Sunday Jan 2018')` não me retornaria somente a data fim ?

Comment: 19 do 11 tá na 47?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim a semana **47** inicia no dia **19/11** e vai até **25/11**

Comment: https://ideone.com/Rvg4pb

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Esse retorno é o ultimo dia da semana 46 ?

Comment: incompatibilidade, na pergunta domingo é o primeiro dia e no comentário a semana começa na segunda

Comment: pegar o primeiro dia da semana 47 (Domingo) e o ultimo dia (Sábado). e no comentário a semana 47 inicia no dia 19/11 e vai até 25/11  dia 19 é segunda-feira

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Verdade, cometi esse erro na hora da pergunta, mas enfim. Acho que esse método que você passou vai resolver meu problema.

Comment: Lembrando que a definição de primeiro dia da semana varia conforme o lugar, cultura, religião, etc e dependendo pode ser domingo, segunda ou até sábado: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-first-day-of-the-week. Se não me engano, no PHP `setISODate` usa a [definição da ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), que usa a segunda-feira como o primeiro dia do ano, e para definir a primeira semana do ano, considera que é a semana que começa em uma segunda e tem pelo menos 4 dias em 2018: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4dedf06de8252117df8837c4895864aae0a375e3

Comment: Nesse caso o ultimo dia seria https://ideone.com/t1Kk3y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar data do ultimo dia (domingo) [ideone](https://ideone.com/k64JpT)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$date = new DateTime();

$date->setISODate(2018, 47, 7);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

> e para o primeiro dia retire a `, 7` ou seja,  `$date->setISODate(2018, 47);`

**Bonus - retornando um array** [ideone](https://ideone.com/Y9DgRa)

```
 function pegarInicioFimSemana($semana, $ano) { $dto = new DateTime(); $dto->setISODate($ano, $semana); $ret['primeiro_dia'] = $dto->format('d-m-Y'); $dto->modify('+6 days'); $ret['ultimo_dia'] = $dto->format('d-m-Y'); return $ret; } $semana_array = pegarInicioFimSemana(47,2018); print_r($semana_array);
```